# What the difference between module and namespace for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have config in my application.rb for loading all models from subfolders:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

Lets assume, that I want to create model Bar in /models/foo/bar.rb

And now i can namespace the model Bar into folder Foo and name it like this:

```
class Foo::Bar
end
```

An opposite approach is to place it into module:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Name of the class from global namespace in both cases is the same.

Considering, that i do not need to include this module or include to this module, and made this only for placing models from one domain in namespace, what is the difference between these approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One different is that your second example does not work if you also want to have a `Foo` class:

```
class Foo
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
# => TypeError: Foo is not a module

class Foo::Bar
end
# no error
```

Comment: You are right, but i expect troubles with first approach. First of all, I dont understand what does it mean if we name class like Foo::Bar. Is it just a name that imitates class inside a module, or Rails do something when see such naming? (may be creates module with appropriate name)